# JQuery HoverIntent not working with Webpack and the ProvidePlugin

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, webpack

I have the following...

webpack.config.js

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  ...
}),
```

deps.ts

```
require('jquery-hoverintent/jquery.hoverIntent.js');
```

test.coffee

```
$('.item').hoverIntent 
  over: ->
    console.log("The hover is working");
```

When I run the application I get...

```
$(...).hoverIntent is not a function
```

Can someone see what I am missing?

**Update**

In jquery.hoverIntent I notice that it is taking the AMD path here...

```
(function(factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(function () {
            return factory // Taking this path
        });
    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory;
    } else if (jQuery && !jQuery.fn.hoverIntent) {
        factory(jQuery);
    }
})(function($) {
    'use strict';

    if ($.fn.hoverIntent) {
        return; 
    }
    ...
})
```

So I tried this in my typescript...

```
var test = require('jquery-hoverintent');
test(window['$']);
```

But when I run in the factory function `$` is undefined despite `window['$']` being valid...

```
> $
undefined
> window['$']
$(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

**Update 2**

This seems to work, however, I thought this was what the plugin was doing as well...

```
window['$'] = window['jQuery'] = require('jquery');
...
require('jquery-hoverintent')(window['$']);
```

So why does that work and not using the Provide Plugin.

Answer (score 3):

As you stated, hoverIntent doesn't use proper a proper amd-style definition, and therefore an extra step is needed when including it in webpack. It doesn't need the Provide plugin or need to use jquery attached to the window, however. I was able to get it to work with:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('jquery-hoverintent')($);
```